# Redirecting HTTP traffic to homepage/root

Tags: django, python-2.7

in effort to avoid user playing with URL, i have added this line to myproject's url.py

```
(r'(.+\.*)$',RedirectView.as_view(url='/')),
```

no matter what ever user try in the browser url it will take user to home page. Good!

problem starts whenever i try to download any thing from my site. is there any way that i can add exception for type of file e.g jpg, gif and let rest of the http traffic goes to homepage/root

my updated views.py

```
def my_view(request):
    my_object = get_object_or_404(Document, pk=1)

def list(request):
    # Handle file upload

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()
        docfile = request.FILES['docfile']
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myproject.myapp.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form


    documents = Document.objects.all()
    return render_to_response(
        'myapp/list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

it giving Server Error 505 now

Comment: 1) `my_view` should return something. 2) Remove `docfile = request.FILES['docfile']` or fix the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Bad 1: You shield off useful error pages.
Bad 2: Django isn't a webserver so don't serve static content with Django.

If a user requests a page that doesn't exist the common thing to do is return a 404 page not found. The 404 page should inform the visitor what happened and what to do next.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/doesnotexcist/

> Django can also be configured to email errors about broken links (404
>   “page not found” errors). Django sends emails about 404 errors when:
>   DEBUG is False; Your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting includes
>   django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/error-reporting/#errors

Now you can fix your broken links when needed and if you get users fiddling the url just see it as a  feature request. With a catch all redirect you're in the dark.

**UPDATE: How to raise 404**

In your views.py you can try to get an object and if it does not exists raise a 404 not found:

```
from django.http import Http404

def my_view(request):
    try:
        my_object = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
    except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
```

But cleaner is to use a shortcut function:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

    def my_view(request):
        my_object = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=1)
```

There is also a `get_list_or_404`. More about the returning 404, shortcuts and writing views  on: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#django.http.Http404

When you raise Http404 from within a view, Django loads and renders the template 404.html if you created it in your root template directory. So add a template the template. Create a file called 404.html in /project/templates/ :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}HTTP 404 - Page not found{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>HTTP404</h1>
    <p>Snap! Something went wrong. The page you requested could not be found!</p>
    <!-- Present some navigation alternatives -->
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Note that this is the presentation for humans. But the real important bit is the status code of the returned data:

```
allcaps$ curl -I https://stackoverflow.com/doesnotexcist/
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 18290
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Fri, 27 Sep 2013 08:50:43 GMT
```

The `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` tells crawler bots that they shouldn't index the page.

Note: If DEBUG is True, Django displays the useful 404 error page with traceback intended for developers. But if DEBUG is False (production), then it displays the template we just created. So make sure that in settings.py `DEBUG = False` to test the template you just created.

Comment: handeling 404 in DJANGO is a nightmare for me. is there any good example to do it, might be i am missing the trick. i want to same as you recommended Example: http://stackoverflow.com/doesnotexcist/. please i am really stuck with 404

Comment: See my updated answer. Raising 404 is also part of the Django 'Getting started' tutorial. Chapter 3: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-get-object-or-404

Comment: i have put views.py in original  its giving 505 once i make DEBUG = False. what do you mean by PRODUCTION? i am not using APACHE just running it through python manage.py runserver

Comment: Production is sort for 'production environment' or 'production code' it is your project on the server machine. Opposed to the development environment and project code on your local machine. The project code in production (on the server) will have DEBUG=False and serves your visitors the useful 404. Your project in development (local machine) will have DEBUG=True and will serve you the Django 404 traceback. To be able to see the 404 intended for your visitors you have to set DEBUG=False.

Comment: i am not moving to production near soon. i apply your instruction on DEV and get 500. please advise what option i have now. can we change the default 404 page's text? or i have to use apache?. there is no comprehensive post on apache & dajngo 1.5

Comment: There is no need to use Apache. The build in development server is fine. First: Set DEBUG=True. Without feedback you are blind. Second: Did you do the Django tutorial? Do it, it saves you time. Everything that we discus here in this tread is mentioned in de tutorial.

Comment: thanks for your help.i set up apache, make Debug=False, put **Allowedhosts** in settings.py and now thing are ok, now for any non-existing page i get **Not Found,the requested URL /fakelink was not found on this server** which is great but now there is one other issue. once i click on uploaded file it also give me **Not Found,The requested URL /media/foo.csv was not found on this server.** it was perfect before. any ideas

Comment: Did I answer your initial question on 'How to redirect and/or 404'? If yes, please accept the answer. For setting up Apache and serving media files you can open a new question. Pointers are: The Django Docs on serving static media and make sure Apache serves the files from the static and media directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a not match in your regex `(r'.+\^jpeg|jpg|gif)',RedirectView.as_view(url='/')),`.

Alternately, specify a URL that catches those cases in lines above the blanket match.

Yet another option would be a blank match, which I believe supports passing media extensions. `(r'',RedirectView.as_view(url='/')),`

Finally, you can rely on a front end web server to serve the media content. For example my media and static live at media.domain.com, and are served as a virtual server via nginx.

Edit: Your best bet is probably going to be a proper 404 handler which redirects as needed - See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views.

I still recommend separating your media into a virutal server of it's own in your web server.

Comment: Would you use such url patterns? Although you answer the question about formatting a regular expression it's not the way to go. The part about serving static content is valid.

Comment: @DivinusVox, fire up few combinations but nothing work. (r'(^csv|xlsx)',RedirectView.as_view(url='/myblog/blog')), please provide full syntax. tried blank also as  (r'',RedirectView.as_view(url='/myblog/blog/')), i am a new to django, so please pardon my ignorance

Comment: same, if redirection works then file is not able to save as. i tried the Http 404 also but it still show DJANGO Error page